# make a Toggle button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a toggle button with it's current css background-color value as 'red'.
on first click it should change to 'yellow', 
on second click it changes to 'green', and
on third it should change back to 'red'.

**HTML**

`<div id="box" class="boxa"> 1 </div>`

**Javascript:**

```
$('div[id="box"]').mousedown(function(){


if($(this).css ('background-color', 'red')) {
       $(this).css ('background-color', 'yellow');    
 }  

});
```

But this doesn't work as `$(this).css ('background-color', 'red')` always returns true,
then tried storing the value in a variable and then checking like this

```
var color = $(this).css ('background-color');
if (color=="red") {
   // change it to some other color
}
```

But this doesn't work either as `color` returns value in RGB.
Can anyone help me write a working solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than checking the current colour, *know* the current colour!

```
var colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'green'];
var currentColor = 0;
```

Then the change becomes nice and straightforward:

```
$('#box').mousedown(function () {
    currentColor++;
    var newColor = colors[currentColor % colors.length];

    $(this).css('background-color', newColor);
});
```

Comment: can you please explain `colors[currentColor % colors.length]`?

Comment: @RameshPareek: `currentColor % colors.length` is the remainder when `currentColor` is divided by `colors.length`. As `currentColor` increases 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, …, `currentColor % colors.length` is 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, …. In other words, it makes it wrap back to the start of the array after you reach the end.

Comment: Interesting logic!

Answer (score 0):

A **less elaborated** approach could be:

JS (jQuery):

```
$(".toggledRed").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("toggledYellow");
}); 


$(".toggledYellow").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("toggledGreen");
}); 


$(".toggledGreen").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("toggledRed");
});
```

CSS:

```
.toggledRed{
    background-color:#FF0000;
}

.toggledYellow{
    background-color:#FFFF00;
}

.toggledBlue{
    background-color:#0000FF;
}
```

And start your HTML with:

```
<div id="box" class="toggledRed"> 1 </div>
```

Should work.

Comment: It’ll work with a minor change: event delegation. `$('#box').parent().on('click', '.toggledRed', …);`. Otherwise `$('.toggledYellow')` and `$('.toggledGreen')` won’t select anything and no event listeners will be added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code: (not very elegant but functional, LOL)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#b1').click(function() {
    var b = $(this);
    if (b.hasClass("red-class")) {
      b.removeClass("red-class");
      b.addClass("yellow-class");
    } else
    if (b.hasClass("yellow-class")) {
      b.removeClass("yellow-class");
      b.addClass("green-class");
    } else
    if (b.hasClass("green-class")) {
      b.removeClass("green-class");
      b.addClass("red-class");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 5px;
}
label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
input[type=text] {
  width: 20em
}
p {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
.green-class {
  background-color: #2b542c;
}
.red-class {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
.yellow-class {
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Change Color in Button</label>
<button id="b1" class="green-class">Hello</button>
```

---

[JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/zerojohnsoft/atg5m6ym/2833/)